# iPads half speed on Airport Extreme

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, airport

It seems like on my network, all my iPad devices run at half the speed of the other devices.

So I tested it.  I've got an airport extreme (1TB) 802.11n, and four devices plus a macbook and they are all connecting to the 5GHZ address, and tied to a 100MB Comcast Cable connection.  I reset the network in settings on all the devices (to start from a common baseline) and ran Ookla speed tests on them one at a time.  The results verified my impression:

```
iPad 2      - 40MB Down / 6MB Up
iPad Air    - 37MB Down / 6MB Up
iPhone 6    - 89MB Down / 6MB Up
iPhone 5c   - 84MB Down / 6MB Up
Macbook Air - 89MB Down / 6MB Up
```

The configurations are the same for all devices, all connecting to the 5GHZ network (I turned off the slower 2.4Ghz network for this test) but no matter how many times I run the test, both of the iPads perform slower.  And it's more than just a speed loss, there is a genuine impression that they access the internet less reliably and slower than the iPhones or laptop.

Does anyone know why this is?  Or better yet, a workaround?

Comment: and the Ping value are same as well? and the RSSI, TR and MCS ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Yes. (The ping at least, I don't know how to check RSSI, TR or MCS)

Comment: Did you try changing the Channel on the router? and not having all connected at same time?

Comment: Tried different channels.  Auto seems to work the best.  Ping tests were run at different times (Sequentially), and I've also tried assigning specific IP's to the different devices.  No joy there.  Turning off other devices on network seems to have no effect.

Comment: I have to say your iPhones and MBA get impressive numbers (80+), I have same set up and only get about 50Mbps on my MBA.

Comment: Yeah, problem is that it's my wife who uses the iPad :) always complaining about it going slow. 1st world problems. @Buscar웃SD do you get similar speeds on iPad?

Comment: No iPad here :( but she should not be "noticing" anything with 40Mbps unless running movie streaming.